# How can I adapt my Kotlin Higher-Order function to take a parameter?

Tags: kotlin, anko

In `Kotlin` I have the following:

```
fun ViewManager.controlButton(body: () -> Unit) = frameLayout {
...
}

private fun captureAndInsert() {
    println("captureAndInsert is called!")
}
```

Inside an `Anko` view:

```
controlButton(this@MemoryFragmentUi::captureAndInsert)
```

This works fine.

Now I need to pass a parameter to `captureAndInsert` so it will look like this:

```
private fun captureAndInsert(myInt: Int) {
    println("captureAndInsert is called!")
}
```

How can I adapt `ViewManager.controlButton` and the call inside the `Anko` view to accept the parameter?

**EDIT**:

Ok, so I can do this:

```
fun ViewManager.controlButton(body: (myInt: Int) -> Unit) = frameLayout {
...
}
```

But how do I call that from the `Anko` view?

Comment: you can still call it with the function reference

Comment: @s1m0nw1 Thanks.  Let's say I want to call it with the param 5.  How do I do that?  `this@MemoryFragmentUi::captureAndInsert(5)` gives an error: `This syntax is reserved for future use.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accept an `(Int) -> Unit` function, you simply need to add the `Int` parameter to the function type in `controlButton` parameter:

```
fun ViewManager.controlButton(body: (Int) -> Unit) = frameLayout {
    ...
}
```

The call of `body` happens inside `controlButton`, so you also need to pass the argument for the lambda to the parameter list of `controlButton`:

```
fun ViewManager.controlButton(body: (Int) -> Unit, v: Int) = frameLayout {
    body(v)
}

//call
controlButton(this@MemoryFragmentUi::captureAndInsert, 5)
```